# DIY USB 3 Way Splitter on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: usb, pi-zero, usb-hub

I am making a portable raspberry pi zero, and I need to have a USB sound card, wi-fi dongle/adapter, and one extra usb port (for keyboard, mouse, etc) all connected to the micro USB port on the Raspberry Pi Zero.

I could buy something like this:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-4-in-1-Micro-USB-Hub-OTG-Cable-Extension-Adapter-for-Android-Samsung-Tablet-/231719134796?hash=item35f389664c:g:WaUAAOSwu4BV0o5l
But it takes up a lot of space when your trying to jam a mini keyboard+trackpad, d-pad, buttons, battery, Pi, usb sound card, Teensy Board, HDMI cable, voltage step up board, etc all in a case a little bigger than a Nintendo DSi XL.

Would it be possible just to strip a micro USB cable and solder wires with these:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/262461043470
connected in parallel and connect all of the USB devices to those? It would function pretty much the same as a regular USB hub, but without any circuitry.

Would this work like a USB hub? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If that would work, someone would have manufactured it like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. USB hubs have active circuitry that controls the data flow (and also power requirements) of slave devices.

You could strip the circuitry out of a USB hub, although I'm not sure how much space you would save by doing that.

Comment: Oh, so things like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-2-0-A-Male-To-2-Dual-Female-Jack-Y-Splitter-Hub-Power-Cord-Adapter-Cable-HU/231862048830?_trksid=p2045573.c100034.m2102&_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D38530%26meid%3Dae7a82c829474608851e1387ec3d212e%26pid%3D100034%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D8%26sd%3D222209608467 are only for power, right?

Comment: @GreenPlasma correct, and they don't comply with USB standards, if you're into that kind of thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a USB hub that stacks in the same footprint as your Pi and this model even alllows you to maintain access to the GPIO pins. [image]

Note these come in two models, one for the original Pi Zero and one for the Pi Zero with camera connector.

Comment: Alternatively you could use something like that:
[USB OTG Hub](https://amzn.com/B01AU8E25A)

Comment: OK. Thanks for such a fast and detailed answer! I appreciate the help.